# How would I create the iOS 7 interactive pop animation, but for a push?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiviewcontroller

iOS 7 [added interactive view controller transitions](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/), and it's really great. I see that it's pretty simply to accomplish, but I'm simply looking for an effect that would be the mirror of the default pop animation.

(The animation where you slide from the left edge of the screen to the right, and the view controllers title shifts right and the view of the view controller you're transitioning to is underneath.)

Like I said, this is obviously built in as an interactive pop transition, but I want to mirror it as an interactive *push* transition, to allow the user to go forward by sliding from the *right edge of the screen to the left*.

Is there a simple way to do this, where it's just a mirror of the other animation? Or do I have to construct it from scratch, which would be slightly cumbersome with the fades, and layer shadowing.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot assign a `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` without having specified a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` object, which means re-implementing the push animation. It's not too hard, but it is annoying that Apple didn't expose the standard push animator for us.